# With which verb can I park a car?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, verbs, word-request, modern-life

What would be a good Latin translation for the verb "to park"?
I mean contexts like "I parked my car in front of his house".
I would prefer to have a classically attested verb, so my main question is this:
How was parking a land vehicle typically expressed in classical Latin?
I want to exclude naval vessels and horses, but I assume the same expression would be equally valid for chariots, wagons, cars, and bicycles.
Verbs like *ponere* and *relinquere* are certainly understandable, but I'm not sure if there is something better.
What would you suggest, and why so?

Comment: You might want to be aware of the origin of "park": http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=park&allowed_in_frame=0

Comment: @C.M.Weimer. The new version of the Oxford English Dictionary argues that it is more likely to be a borrowing from Romance to Germanic rather than the other way around. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/137946?rskey=7PxySm&result=1#eid

Comment: @fdb Interesting, though even so, it seems the development in meaning is nearly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that the concept of vehicle parking was *quite* as familiar to the Romans as it is to us in the modern world, so an attested classical usage may be hard to find. But if you had wanted to park anything casually, from a *cisium* to a *quadriga*, I suggest that you would either choose a *stabularius*, a person to guard your property for money, or find a *locus statarius*, where you might simply 'park' it (equally, if relying on public transport, you might have found a *rheda publica* waiting for you at a similar spot).

As to a more permanent place in which to leave your means of transport, *stabula equorum* or *vehiculorum* might serve. Smith offers a suggestion for 'livery stables', *stabula caballorum mercenaria*.

Because it conveys the sense of going off somewhere, rather than simply of depositing, I would much prefer *relinquo* to *pono* as the verb to use. When you arrived at your actual destination, you might say *Cisium in loco statario reliqui.*